# Is it possible to retrieve the shared event properties (owned by the organizers calendar) from an attendee's copy?

Tags: api, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I would like to retrieve from the Google Calendar API the shared event properties from an attendee's copy after the attendee made changes to that copy. Is this somehow possible without having access to the organizers calendar?

Background: I sync the calendar properties of a user into another calendar. But I would like to show the event in the same way as the organizer has it in his/her calendar and would like to disregard eventual changes that the attendee/ user of the portal has made in his/ her Google calendar (e.g. changed subject, time, etc.).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the attendee's copy of the event? @Vital

Comment: Each guest/attendee keeps a copy of the original event (in the organizers calendar) in his/her calendar. Google allows to change that copy without notifying the organizer. For example, it is possible to change the subject or time of the event. However, the original event in the organizers calendar nor the copies of the other guests/attendees are changed. What I am looking for is a way to find out if a “copy” of a guest deviates from the organizers original event.

Comment: Are you the guests from the same domain? Or are you the admin of the domain? @Vital